# Css compression - Vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I use vuetify, with a nuxt project and when I look at the page source I see 26k lines of code and around99% of it css comes from vuetify. and when Icheck some other pages page souce I see less lines of code with unreadable css. Should I do something explicitly for this? I didnt change anything from nuxt.config for vuetify

```
vuetify: {
customVariables: ['~/assets/variables.scss'],
theme: {
  dark: false,
  themes: {
    dark: {
      primary: colors.blue.darken2,
      accent: colors.grey.darken3,
      secondary: colors.amber.darken3,
      info: colors.teal.lighten1,
      warning: colors.amber.base,
      error: colors.deepOrange.accent4,
      success: colors.green.accent3
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. You do not have to do anything explicitly. The page source you are seeing just development version of your page. In the production, that will be handled by Nuxt.

For a quick test, try `nuxt start` and see the page source again.